# Instagram api pagination object is coming blank ( empty ) in live mode

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api, codeigniter-3

we are facing a major issue on the Instagram API calling section using PHP (Codeigniter 3). First of all we want to tell you that our app in in live mode and we are very sure of that . The pagination URL object is coming blank after 20 images and we have tried different ways using the COUNT parameter on the section and the next_max_id and next_min_id but all in vain. So please suggest us some new way to do this section. We can not use javascript on this section according to our requirements.

Some of the small example are below how e call the api and what are we using.

---

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=3963420514.440235f.df3a5b4f9d6546cb9512ffd0a13ae62f&count=13

---

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3963420514/media/recent?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us what you have tried so far and include some code in your question and provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

I checked your API response it has `pagination` data

just use the `pagination.next_url` to get the next set of 13 posts via API, I tried it, it worked with your API above.

If not you can also maually add `&max_id={value of pagination.next_max_id}` to the API to get next set of posts

Comment: Thank you for  that, but we have already figured it out what was the problem and we have solve the issue . The code you have give is already done in our section using a recursive function any way thanks  :)